# GCE ingress health checks failing on kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run a bitcoin node on kubernetes. My stateful set is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: bitcoin-stateful
  namespace: dev
spec:
  serviceName: bitcoinrpc-dev-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bitcoin-node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bitcoin-node
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bitcoin-node-mainnet
        image: myimage:v0.13.2-addrindex
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8332 
        volumeMounts:
        - name: bitcoin-chaindata
          mountPath: /root/.bitcoin
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            -  bitcoin-cli
            -  getinfo
          initialDelaySeconds: 60 #wait this period after staring fist time
          periodSeconds: 15  # polling interval
          timeoutSeconds: 15    # wish to receive response within this time period
        readinessProbe: 
          exec:
            command:
            -  bitcoin-cli
            -  getinfo
          initialDelaySeconds: 60 #wait this period after staring fist time
          periodSeconds: 15    # polling interval
          timeoutSeconds: 15    # wish to receive response within this time period
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["-c","service ntp start && \
                    bitcoind -printtoconsole -conf=/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -reindex-chainstate -datadir=/root/.bitcoin/ -daemon=0 -bind=0.0.0.0"]
```

Since, the bitcoin node doesn't serve any http get requests and only can serve post requests, I am trying to use `bitcoin-cli` command for `liveness` and `readiness probe`

My service is as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bitcoinrpc-dev-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: bitcoin-node
  ports:
  - name: mainnet
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8332
```

When I describe the pods, they are running ok and all the health checks seem to be ok.

However, I am also using ingress controller with the following config:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "dev-ingress"
spec:
  rules:
        - host: bitcoin.something.net
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /rpc
          backend:
            serviceName: bitcoinrpc-dev-service
            servicePort: 80
```

The health checks on the L7 load balancer seem to be failing. The tests are automatically configured in the following manner.

[image]

However, these tests are not the same as the ones configured in the readiness probe. I tried to delete the ingress and recreate however, it still behaves the same way.

I have the following questions:

```
1. Should I modify/delete this health check manually?
2. Even if the health check is failing (wrongly configured), since the containers and ingress are up, does it mean that I should be able to access the service through http?
```

Answer (score 0):

What is is missing is that you are performing the liveness and readiness probe as exec command, therefor you need to create a pod that includes an Exec readiness probe and other pod that includes Exec readiness probe as well, [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) and [Here](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/kubernetes-liveness-readiness-probes) is described how to do it.

Another thing is to receive traffic through the GCE L7 Loadbalancer Controller you need:
At least 1 Kubernetes [NodePort Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services.md#type-nodeport) (this is the endpoint for your Ingress), so your service is not configured well. therefor you will not be able to able to access the service.

The health check in picture in for the Default backend (where your MIG is using it to check the health of the node) that mean your nodes health check not the container.

Comment: 1. Is configuring the `liveness` and `readiness` probe configured in the stateful set above not sufficient? </br>


2. A nodeport service is actually present. I checked that the nodeport in the health check matches that in the service.


3. In that case, how can I debug if there is something wrong with the node?

Comment: first try to remove the readinees and liveness prob and check if everything is working. Second you may need to change .spec.podManagementPolicy for a StatefulSet from OrderedReady to Parallel policy. with this alternative policy is Parallel which will create pods in parallel. i'm not sure about this but give it try.

This way K8S will start all your pods in parallel and won't wait for probes.

From [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#statefulsetspec-v1-apps)

Comment: I tried removing readiness and liveness probe, I still get the same error. About `spec.podManagementPolicy`, I am currently running only 1 independent pod, so don't think it's related

Comment: One thing that i forgot and i just noticed it's the gce (GLBC) ingress, therefor you should add star to your path - path: /rpc/* as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce)

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't have to delete the health check as it will get created automatically even if you delete it.
2. No, you won't be able to access the services until the health checks pass because the traffic in case of gke is passed using NEGs which depend on health checks to know where they can route traffic to.

One possible solution this could be that you need to add a basic http router to your application that returns `200`, this can be used health check endpoint.

Other possible options include:

1. Creating a service of type NodePort and using LoadBalancer to route traffic on the given port to the node pool/instance groups as backend service rather than using NEG
2. Create the service of type LoadBalancer. This step is the easiest but you need to ensure that the load balancer ip is protected using best security policies like IAP, firewall rules, etc.